# Marker drop event in google maps?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I need to trigger an event when the user drops a marker on the map. I have the code working for them to drop the marker, but I can't figure out how to trigger the event.

Any tips?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

With Marker event dragend you have the latlng where the Marker is drop. This is that you need?

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, "dragend", function(event) { 
          var lat = event.latLng.lat(); 
          var lng = event.latLng.lng(); 
        });
```